# Laravel Eloquent Relationship FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 9573:Class Lecture not found

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to make a one-to-many relationship between Item and Lecture, where Lecture has many items;

Here's my `Lecture` migration table:

```
        Schema::create('lectures', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->integer('lecturer');
        });
```

Here's my `Item` migration table:

```
        Schema::create('items', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 255);
            $table->integer('lecture_id');

            $table->foreign('lecture_id')->references('id')
                ->on('lectures');
        });
```

Finally here's how I connect them together:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function lecture()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Lecture', 'lecture_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Lecture extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item', 'lecture_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I wonder what's wrong and why am I keep getting the error. I've tried `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan migrate:refresh`, and `php artisan db:seed`. But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5, you need to add the "use" lines to your code when using other classes.

If your lecture model class is right under the app directory, you need to add

```
use App\Lecture;
```

to your PHP codes/classes which require it.

Comment: Thanks, although this is not exactly it, but I found the error was because I didn't use a full path. I should've written `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AMS1B\Lecture', 'lecture_id', 'id');` instead of only `Lecture`